# Filesystem-based web content

Tags: java, filesystems, crm, opencms

I plan to pull my Java web apps's content from a filesystem, for the sake of simplicity of editing. These files will be most probably only a text in a simple markup like JTexy or Markdown.

What I plan to implement is a tree-like structure keeping the content of the files.
It should be cached and eventually should handle authorization.

I am looking for a simple-to-use thing, not a full-blown CMS like OpenCMS, but if it provides a simple api to access the content and can keep it's dependencies small, the other stuff like thick client content editors is a bonus.

Perhaps something from this list: http://java-source.net/open-source/content-managment-systems

What would you recommend?

Thanks,
Ondra

Comment: > "...CRM like OpenCMS"... OpenCms is not a CRM, it's a CMS. OpenCms does have WebDAV support though, so you can in fact edit the files on your desktop with your preferred editor. But for your purpose OpenCms is probably not the best tool though.
btw: Why did you tag your question with OpenCms, if that's what you're NOT looking for?

Comment: Ah, yeah, that was a typo. Fixed.
And I tagged it to bring the attention of people knowing such solutions, who are likely to know some similar tools.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a simple Apache webserver with a (f)cgi perl script to convert the markdown and a mod_proxy to cache the results.

Beeautiful in its simplicity!

Comment: I forgot to write - the content will be used in the web app. Do you suggest to do a local HTTP request from the web app?

Comment: For what I gather from your requirements you wont even need a web application. You can have static HTML pages in the apache server, use a markdown cgi script to render the pages coming from disk. For updating you can use a simple upload CGI (which come a dime a dozen) or some javascript and the mod_dav module of apache. This will allow  you to focus on content and layout and not have a application server to draw attention away. I really like your concept : back to basics :-)

Comment: I'd love to have it that simple... but I already have the Java web app :) And it's quite dynamic... I look for a solution for static content - simple, yet thread-safe, mageable, searchable, scalable.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not intend to reinvent wheels then you should probably use a CMS.

As you write OpenCms is a full-blown CMS", but it also should be "simple-to-use" in your context.